# AJAX remember generated element style

Tags: ajax

I have a website where i generate some divs with data. I re-generate these after each 60 seconds to have up to date data. I have added a fullscreen-button to each div, giving the div a `.fullscreen` class with javascript. This makes the div `fixed position`, `100% width` and `100% height`.

When the divs get regenerated, the `.fullscreen` on a div is not remembered. Is there any smart way to achieve this? So the divs get updated, and the particular div with `.fullscreen` gets the class again.

The website is made in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6.

**Example structure**

```
<div id="container">

   <div class="tile">data...</div>
   <div class="tile">data...</div>
   <div class="tile fullscreen">data...</div>
   <div class="tile">data...</div>

</div>
```

After ajax call, the container is replaced with the following (clearing the `.fullscreen` class)

```
  <div id="container">

       <div class="tile">data...</div>
       <div class="tile">data...</div>
       <div class="tile">data...</div>
       <div class="tile">data...</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: You can use javascript to take of that.

$("#container").append(
    $('<div>').attr('id', 'container').addClass(fullscreen').html('New element')
);

Comment: @Thennarasan Yes. But i need to know **which** div to give the fullscreen class.

Comment: If you know what are the div tags that you want to give. You can index that and update.

`$(document.getElementById('container').children[2]).addClass('fullscreen');`

Comment: @Thennarasan What div the user pressed to fullscreen is unknown. I need a way to know what `children[?]` it is. So remembering the index server-side or client side cross ajax-calls somehow.

Comment: Quite simple.. do that in on click.

`$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
  $(".tile").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(this).addClass("active");      //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});`

Comment: @Thennarasan this is exactly what i do. But when the divs get replaced by AJAX, the .active class is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ajax success function

```
//Get position of div where success class is applied
var index_fs=$( "#container > div" ).index($("#container > div.fullscreen"));

// your code  should be here for remove and append all div

// if index of fullscreeen is found means >=0
if(index_fs>=0)
{
    $( "#container > div:eq("+index_fs+")" ).addClass("fullscreen");
}
```

Comment: I like the idea. But it does not work.  `index_fs` is always ` -1`.

Comment: Sorry. i misspelled something. This works perfectly! Thanks!